# when I include atomic.h, GCC says No such file, why?

Tags: linux, gcc, header, compiler-errors

I want to use atomic API, and I include . I don't know how to use it! Thank you!

---

I have it in `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-11/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic.h`.

I also add `-I/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-11/arch/x86/include/` and  `-I/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-11/include`.

Some other errors is produced because of `-DCONFIG_X86_32` and `-D__KERNEL__ macro undefined`.

Then I define the two macros,

### some errors occurred:

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-11/include/linux/cpumask.h:600:37: error: "and" may not appear in macro parameter list

/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-11/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:159:1: warning: "cache_line_size" redefined

/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-11/include/linux/cache.h:64:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition

/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-11/include/linux/stddef.h:16: error: expected identifier before ‘false’
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-11/include/linux/stddef.h:16: error: expected `}' before ‘false’
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-11/include/linux/stddef.h:16: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘false’
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-11/include/linux/stddef.h:18: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
```

My system is `ubuntu 9.04` running on `Virtualbox3.0`.

Comment: Do you actually have the header file? Is it in GCCs include path?

Comment: please post your #include statement, and the full command you are using to compile.

Comment: g++ -c -I/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-11/arch/x86/include -I/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-11/include -DCONFIG_X86_32 -D__KERNEL__ mySource.cpp

Comment: #include <asm/atomic.h> in my file.

Answer (score 1):

If you know where the file is on your HD, then you say gcc mySource.c -I/path/to/atomic

note that this assumes you include "atomic" directly. and not "some/path/atmomic.h"